# Vanishing popup alert view

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uiviewanimation

I'd like to popup a view with a single label in it that disappears slowly within one second to inform the user about a choice he made, an update occurred or whatever.

I use animatewithduration, but because they may be many different alerts, I'd like to create a class to avoid creating view, label and func in any UIViewController that may display that kind of alert ... Kind of :

```
let doneAlert = PopUpAlert(parentView : self, textAlert : "You're done")
```

where parentView in the view where I want the textAlert to be displayed and then when needed:

```
doneAlert.display()
```

Here's the class I wrote :

```
class PopUpAlert: UIView {

convenience init(parentView : UIView,textAlert : String) {
    self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 150))

    self.alpha = 0
    self.center = parentView.center

    let popUpLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 150))
    popUpLabel.center = self.center
    popUpLabel.text = textAlert

    self.addSubview(popUpLabel)
    parentView.addSubview(self)
 }


func display() {
    PopUpAlert.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)

    PopUpAlert.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)

 }

}
```

And here's the way I use it :

```
class CarteVC: UIViewController {

var daddy : RootViewController?
var goAlert : PopUpAlert?
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    goAlert = PopUpAlert(parentView: mapView, textAlert: "On the way ....")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let bb = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< List", style: .Plain, target: papa!, action: "pred")
    bb.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    daddy!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = bb
    daddy!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

    goAlert!.display()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }



// MARK: - Navigation
```

Nothing is displayed.

Comment: Found it ..... It's only a question a positionning .... no more popUpLabel.center ... and it appears !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pb came from centering the label inside the view ... Here's the class and works perfectly fine !!! :

```
class PopUpAlert: UIView {

convenience init(parentView : UIView,textAlert : String) {
    self.init(parentView: parentView,textAlert: textAlert,background: UIColor.darkGrayColor(),foreground: UIColor.whiteColor())
}

convenience init(parentView : UIView,textAlert : String, background : UIColor) {
    self.init(parentView: parentView,textAlert: textAlert,background: background,foreground: UIColor.whiteColor())
}

convenience init(parentView : UIView,textAlert : String, foreground : UIColor) {
    self.init(parentView: parentView,textAlert: textAlert,background: UIColor.darkGrayColor(),foreground: foreground)
}

convenience init(parentView : UIView,textAlert : String, background : UIColor, foreground : UIColor) {
    self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40))

    self.alpha = 0
    self.backgroundColor = background
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.center = (parentView.superview ?? parentView).center

    let popUpLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40))
    popUpLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    popUpLabel.textColor = foreground
    popUpLabel.text = textAlert
    self.addSubview(popUpLabel)

    parentView.addSubview(self)
}

deinit {
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}


func display() {
    PopUpAlert.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.85
        }, completion: nil)

    PopUpAlert.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.7, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just alert user and disappear in one second than i would suggest you to use Toast Swift

https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift

Here is how you make the toast

```
self.view.makeToast("Testing Toast")

// specific duration and position
self.view.makeToast("Testing Toast with duration and position", duration: 3.0, position: .Top)

// toast with image and all possible 
self.view.makeToast("testing toast image and all possible ", duration: 2.0, position: CGPoint(x: 110.0, y: 110.0), title: "Toast Title", image: UIImage(named: "toast.png"), style:nil) { (didTap: Bool) -> Void in
    if didTap {
        print("with tap")
    } else {
        print("without tap")
    }
}
```

Comment: if the answer was useful for you don't forget to accept and upvote.. :)